# How to add values from sharedpreferences to cardview in android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using shared preference to store the user details. Now I want to get the value from shared preferences and to display it in cardview. I used

```
onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder,final int position)
```

method to pass data. How it possible to add shared preferences in adapter class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get value by using this and later on you can bind with your componant

```
Context context = getActivity();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get instance of SharedPreferences you need context. Pass context from activity/fragment to your adapter. Once you have context, get SharedPreferences instances as below :

> ```
> SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
>         getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
> ```

Then you can use sharedPref to access your user details.

It will be better if you maintain an instance of your SharedPreferences at your app level so that you are not creating a new instance everywhere you need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private SharedPreferences preferences;
```

in constructor:

```
preferences = mActivity.getSharedPreferences("pref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

now you can access it in onBindViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

As shared preference is use for storing key value pairs and i am assuming you are using cardview with recyclerview, so you may need list of values.I think its bad practice and you can use sqlite for same purpose,if you want data from database or else you can get dynamically form api(if your app has backend).

You can use following code to get value from shared preference

```
SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
String value = (shared.getString(key, ""));
```

and set this string to cardviews value.